# Encoding paths in a graph as strings?

Tags: mysql, sql, graph-databases, directed-acyclic-graphs

Suppose I have a DAG and, rather than using a graph db, the paths are encoded as `{id:"node3", path:"node0|node1|node2"}` to represent that `node3` can reach `node0` via `node2` then `node1`. Would it be a good idea to encode the path in a string if reads are not frequent? The paths generally don't contain more than 50 nodes each.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will find that your approach won't work as well as you want. One of the properties that makes graphs interesting are the [combinatorial explosions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion) that can occur from their structures. Storing every path for every node is going to get big very fast and I think it would cease to scale and do what you expected.

Consider the following blog posts:

http://thinkaurelius.com/2012/04/21/loopy-lattices/

http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/06/12/loopy-lattices-redux/

The posts explore path counting on 20x20 directed lattice. It finds that a graph "with only 441 vertices and 840 edges, has over 137 billion unique directed paths."